# Как узнать id определенной строки из таблицы PHPmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы с данными пользователей. С каждым входом пользователя на сайт нужно узнать под каким `id` хранятся его данные в первой таблице, чтобы занести другие данные о нем во вторую таблицу. `mysqli_insert_id()` не подходит, т.к. входящий на сайт пользователь не обязательно будет последним зарегистрировавшимся.

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "select * from data where login = '$login' and password = '$password'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['id'];
```

возвращает пустой результат.

Как же все таки узнать `id` определенной строки в таблице и возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Если результат пустой (кстати `пустой` это как?), значит пользователя с таким логином и паролем в базе нет

Comment: Что паказывает `var_dump($row)`?

Comment: Пользователь с таким логином и паролем в базе точно есть.
В браузер не выводится результат sql запроса, который должен содержаться в переменной.
`var_dump($row)` показывает NULL

Comment: Никогда не подставляйте данные в запрос таким образом. Пользуйтесь подготовленными запросами.

Comment: @Ирина Выведите в браузер Ваш SQL запрос, а потом скопируйте эго и выполните в phpmyadmin. Я еще раз говорю - Ваш запрос не возвращает ни одной записи

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Спасибо, разобралась

Comment: @Ирина И в чем была проблема? Оформите как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что перед запросом подключался файл `connect.php`, в котором так же присутствует переменная `$password`. И вместо того, чтобы в запросе проверять пароль, введенный пользователем, проверялся пароль, который используется для связи с базой